# Merge [android4.2] and [android-4.2-jelly-bean]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[[android4.2]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android4.2/info) seems to be an attempted [android-4.2] tag, with the missed `-`, meaning the tag synonym for [[android-4.2-jelly-bean]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-4.2-jelly-bean/synonyms) wasn't activated.

We should fix the tags on those [4 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android4.2?sort=newest) that are mis-tagged. I was going to go through and do it myself, but re-tagging requires 6 characters or more of an edit. I think that high-rep users can merge the tags, or retag without having to make a 'significant' edit.

Comment: I'm quite surprised it was left this long and nobody noticed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I went through and changed the questions over to [android-4.2-jelly-bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-4.2-jelly-bean).  A couple of them were tagged with both tags as well so on those I just remove the [android4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android4.2)